# Regex finding the last occurrence of the highest number after a matching string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have the following text and I want a regex matching the last page of each file:
https://regex101.com/r/DmVnK7/1

The right Regex gives the following result:

```
A_File1_Page1
**A_File1_Page2**

A_File2_Page1
A_File2_Page2
**A_File2_Page3**

B_File1_Page1
B_File1_Page2
**B_File1_Page3**

B_File2_Page1
B_File2_Page2
B_File2_Page3
**B_File2_Page4**

C_File1_Page1
C_File1_Page2
C_File1_Page3
C_File1_Page4
**C_File1_Page5**
```

Comment: /.*Page.\n\n/g this one almost works

Comment: Thanks but my long text doesn't really have empty lines
They are added for easier code reading

Comment: I think this works: selecting the file names before each page1. Can anybody SELECT LAST ".*_Page.d+" BEFORE EACH PAGE 1? 

Comment: grep Page1 -B 1

Comment: /((.*(\n|\r|\r\n)){1}).*Page1/g

Comment: It appears you just need to match `^.*(?=\r?\n?\z|(?:\r?\n){2})`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2CREp/1). The *positive lookahead* (`(?=\r?\n?\z|(?:\r?\n){2})`) asserts that the line matched (`^.*`) is at the end of the string (`\z`), possibly preceded by a line terminator (`\r?\n?`) or (`|`) is followed by two line terminators in a row `(?:\r?\n){2}`).

Comment: @manishma, `{1}` has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regular expression

```
/(^.*_Page)\d+$(?!\r?\n\1\d+$)/gm
```

Or as follows if you require a `.jpg` extension to the match:

```
/(^.*_Page)\d+\.jpg$(?!\r?\n\1\d+\.jpg$)/gm
```

### Example

https://regex101.com/r/Q2Ymk2/1

Or with the `.jpg` extension:
https://regex101.com/r/Z0MSHJ/1

### Description

(Generated by regex101)

- 1st Capturing Group `(^.*_Page)`

  - `^` asserts position at start of a line
  - `.` matches any character (except for line terminators)
  - `*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `_Page` matches the characters `_Page` literally (case sensitive)
- `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`)
- `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line
- Negative Lookahead `(?!\r?\n\1\d+$)`

  - Assert that the Regex below does not match
  - `\r` matches a carriage return (ASCII 13)

    - `?` matches the previous token between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `\n` matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
  - `\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
  - `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to `[0-9]`)
  - `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
  - `$` asserts position at the end of a line

Global pattern flags

- `g` modifier: global. All matches (don't return after first match)
- `m` modifier: multi line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have a problem when I use an extension this regex doesn't work. Can you take a look at: and help me with it: https://regex101.com/r/HT29tB/1

Comment: @LordTesla updated my answer to include an example with `.jpg` extension on the matches.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex, I think only get the last occurrence can be gleaned.
Mostly because there is no regex construct for counting.
If you need to count, match all pages `(.*?Page\d+)` then sort and unique.

If just getting the last page of each is enough, then this

```
(.*?Page)\d+(?![\s\S]*\1)
```

https://regex101.com/r/iP3FcV/1

```
 ( .*? Page )                  # (1)
 \d+ 
 (?! [\s\S]* \1 )
```